# Batch-file: Extracting lines from a .txt file and format them

Tags: variables, batch-file, format, lines

I'm stuck at batch scripting.

I have a `.txt` file with a random number of lines like

```
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
```

I need to get those lines into a variable in my batch file like this:

```
"alpha","bravo","charlie,"delta"
```

It would be awesome if I could write `echo %selections%` in the end and `"alpha","bravo","charlie,"delta"` would be returned!

The number of lines is variable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far? Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Read the following help topics: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with following batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Selections="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("ListFile.txt") do set "Selections=!Selections!,"%%I""
rem Remove comma at beginning of the selections value.
set "Selections=!Selections:~1!"
echo !Selections!
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Note: This code does not check if `ListFile.txt` exists at all. And it does not check if the file is empty or contains only blank lines. And **FOR** as used here skips lines starting with a semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using python,

```
    fhand=read("filename.txt")
    for line in fhand:      *#line reads each line of the textfile one by one*
        words=line.split()*#words will store the words in each line as a list*
        print words
```

Comment: I'm just curious: how did you get the impression that a question about batch-file-scripting could be about `python`?